# Checking multiple conditions in a single If statement - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form in which there are many textBoxes from which three textboxes are required to fill in order to submit the form. I dont want to use each If block for each text box. Is there any way to use a single if statement for all the three text boxes? I am using the following code:

```
if (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox2.Text != "" || textBox4.Text != "")
{
   // Code
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Fill required fields");
}
```

but this code works even a single text fox is filled and the rest of the required text boxes are empty.

Comment: How many textboxes you have in total

Comment: **Suggestion**: use `Trim` on all text box value when comparing to empty string. Or you can use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` with `Trim` to do the comparison.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure: Or with .NET 4.0, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: Right. Was not sure which version OP is using, hence Trim & String.IsNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 if (textBox1.Text != "" &&  textBox2.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "")
 {
     // Code
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Fill required fields");
 }
```

You want *all* conditions to pass. This fits the semantics of the logical AND operator `&&`.

If you have tons of textboxes, I would tend to keep them in a list:

```
var boxes = new List<TextBox>{
     textBox1,
     textBox2,
     textBox3,
     //...
};
if (boxes.Any(tb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Fill required fields");
}
else
{
    // Code
}
```

I also tend to prefer to keep the exception in the `if` part, returning or throwing an error and ommit an `else` part, since that is just normal code flow. This keeps the code you expect to run as far to the left as possible.

Answer (score 5):

You should change `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 3):

You created a collection of `or` statements, so only one needs to be true in order to continue. Instead you need to `and` them:

```
if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "")
```

Answer (score 3):

You may define a method to test empty strings.

```
public class Test
{   
  public static bool IsEmpty(params string []args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0) return true ;
        return args.Any(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p));
    }
}
```

To test strings,

```
if(!Test.IsEmpty(TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text,TextBox3.Text))
 {
   //valid
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use OR (||) and should use AND (&&) instead. You want ALL three textboxes to be non-empty strings. Check out the following code:

```
if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty && textBox2.Text != String.Empty && textBox4.Text != String.Empty)
{
  // Code
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Fill required fields");
}
```

You can also make a collection of TextBoxes and loop through them to check for non-empty Strings. Something like this:

```
List<TextBox> _lstTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
_lstTextBoxes.Add(textBox1);
_lstTextBoxes.Add(textBox2);
_lstTextBoxes.Add(textBox3);

Boolean checkFailed = false;
foreach(TextBox tb in _lstTextBoxes)
  if(tb.Text == String.Empty)
    checkFailed = true;

if(checkFailed)
  MessageBox.Show("Fill required fields");
else
  //code
```

This way you have a more generic approach to which you can easily add or remove certain textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `OR (||)` use `AND (&)` in your condition.

**Suggestion**

- Use `Trim` function from `string` to remove any white spaces from textbox (if required)
- Instead of comparing  like `textBox1.Text != ""` do  `String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) == false`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have 4 textboxes in total, below code will work

```
if ((textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "") || (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "") ||
        (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "") || (textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "")
        )
    {                  
        // Code             
    }             
    else             
    {                 
        MessageBox.Show("Fill required fields");             
    }
```